# CSS or selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using CSS and I have something like this :

```
#id1 #id2 .class1 #id3, #id1 #id2 .class2 #id3
```

I juste wanted to know if there was a way to do something like this :

```
#id1 #id2 .[class1 OR class2] #id3
```

I didn't find a way to do this, but maybe I was not checking Google correctly or something.. Is this possible or do I need to use my LONNNNG syntax ?

Thanks !

Comment: A page *can only have one of each `id`* so technically you can select with just - `#id3`...

Comment: as id should be unique  it should be enough  just #id3 :)

Comment: Yes, this is true in this case ! My question was mostly about if there was an OR selector. You can suppose there is no #id3 at all ! (But in my case, some of my page have a similar structure. For example, there will be an #id3 in many pages (but only one at the time) and #id1 would be the page type). But the question is really about the OR selector :)

Comment: @user3017110: Are you specifically applying properties for class1 or class3 (or) looking for pattern (like class*, *class)? If it is a pure `or`, I don't think there is a way. If patterns, then you have some possible options given in answer :)

Comment: @Harry : I would need a pure or as I don't have a pattern for those class ! But the answer "there is no way to do a "or" exactly as I want" is acceptable to me ! I was just checking if there was a way to reduce my syntax but I'll keep what I have right now ! :)

Comment: @user3017110: With some CSS pre-processors (like Less/Sass etc), there might be a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes start with the same string, you can write your rule as follows:

```
#id2 [class^="class"] {}
```

This will look for everything inside `#id2` that starts with `class`.

You seem to want something like this, though:

```
#id1 #id2 [class^="class"] #id3
```

But as has been pointed out, you should be fine by just using `#id3` because only one ID per page is allowed. Unless, ofcourse, you only want to apply a style when one of its ancestors has a specific class.

For more documentation, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Comment: This is possibly the closest. But onethings to note is this will select all classes which are like class* (not exactly a 1 or 3 type). That is apart from the #id3 selector.

Comment: Thanks ! In my case, the begining or end of the class name is not the same (they are independant word). But I guess the answer is there is no "or" selector to do exactly what I want :)

Comment: @user3017110 I'm afraid not! But it would be easy, wouldn't it. (Don't forget to mark this answer if it helped you.)

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense. What do you want to select altogther?

Your first method is fine, just do it.

Or give a common class and use that.

```
#id1 #id2 .common #id3{}
```

Or if you have class name alike you can use attribute selector;

```
#id1 #id2 [class^="class"] #id3{} /* ^ denotes starting with */
#id1 #id2 [class*="class"] #id3{} /* * denotes anywhere  */
```

[See more about attribute selector here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)